# Determining average values over irregular number of rows in a csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, average

I have a csv file with days of the year in one column and temperature in another. The days are split into sections and I want to find the average temperature over each day.Eg day 0,1,2,3 etc

The measurements of temperatures has been taken irregularly meaning there are different numbers of measurements at certain times for each day.

Typically I would use df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // n).mean() but n, the number of rows will be varying in this case.

I have an example of what the data is like.

| Days | Temp |
| --- | --- |
| 0.75 | 19 |
| 0.8 | 18 |
| 1.2 | 18 |
| 1.25 | 18 |
| 1.75 | 19 |
| 3.05 | 18 |
| 3.55 | 21 |
| 3.60 | 21 |
| 3.9 | 18 |
| 4.5 | 20 |

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `Days` to an integer and use that to group.

```
>>> df.groupby(df["Days"].astype(int)).mean()
       Days       Temp
Days                  
0     0.775  18.500000
1     1.400  18.333333
3     3.525  19.500000
4     4.500  20.000000
```

Comment: If I want to plot the int values of days 0 1 3 4 against time how would that be done? Using df.iloc[:, 1:2] to show the int days and average values of temp only, I’m not able to select the int values of days for my x axis.